# Alternative to xor(A,B,C)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

How can we make a comprehensive statement, which will correspond to the truth table of xor (A, B, C) by combining logical operators AND (&), OR (|), XOR (xor) and NOT (!)?  In other words, the result should be true if an odd number of the terms is true, and false otherwise.

Comment: what do you want xor(A,B,C) to be? should it be xor(xor(A,B),C) or only true if exactly one of A,B,C is true?

Comment: only true if exactly one of A,B,C is true

Answer (score 2):

See [Exclusive or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) :

> $p ⊕ q \equiv (p \lor q) \land \lnot (p \land q)$.

If you want that $XOR(p,q,r)$ must be *true* when exactly one is, you must start from :

> $(p \land \lnot(q \lor r)) \lor (q \land \lnot(p \lor r)) \lor (r \land \lnot(p \lor q))$

i.e.

> $(p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r) \lor (q \land \lnot p \land \lnot r) \lor (r \land \lnot p \land \lnot q)$.

Select from the truth-table all the rows with exactly one *true* and form the [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form).

Comment: It's great, thank you! But, actually, I need such sheme for 3 variables.

Comment: @Markus - You cannot use $(p⊕q)⊕r$ ?

Comment: No, because if $p,q,r$ are all true, then $(p \oplus q) \oplus r$ is also true, which isn't what the OP want

Comment: I suppose that I can but I don't know how to rewrite it by combining logical operators AND (&), OR (|), XOR (xor) and NOT (!)